# MSSQL Turkish Character Problem that i can't display records properly

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, special-characters

I had a translation error on my web service. Because of this some records saved with character error on MSSQL database.
For example

```
İ -> Ä° 
Ö -> Ã<0x96>  -> 'Ã–' 
Ü -> Ã<0x9c>  ->  'Ãœ'  etc.
Ğ -> Ä
```

I can see some characters like 'Ä°', 'Ä' in query  but because of some characters has "<0x96>" (right side character not supported i guess) 3  different character showing  as one character (Ã?). I try to fix records but there are aproximately 5000 records and that 3 same character prevent me to do.

Can i display records with hexadecimal (or the value like 'œ') codes or what can i do?

Ps. In my table i can display Turkish characters from older records.  Checked database settings.
Bad records inserted table like ''Insert into Table(Name) Values ('JÄ°MMY')"
Thank you.

Comment: You can't fix data after the encodes/code pages have been "mistreated" and the data is lost. You need to fix the process that is corrupting the data first, and then re-`INSERT`/`UPDATE` the data.

Comment: I already fixed process but there are bunch of records which has errors. I try to fix that records too. However thank you for response.